# Cordova App doesn't work on web server

Tags: hybrid, hosted-app

I am new to Cordova. 
I have created an Cordova app on Mac and after executing following command
`$` sudo ionic serve -l

I have copied www folder from MyApp/platforms/browser/ and placed it on my web server.

Yesterday, it did work but suddenly it stopped working.
there is some extra code when i access it on my online server using web browser

`<script type = 'text/javascript' id ='1qa2ws' charset='utf-8' src='http://103.255.6.16:8080/www/default/base.js'></script></body><!-- end body section-->`

This is unknown IP address, i have no idea from where it gets that.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

Its my ISP. app is fine.